# Folders List with modified date to text file

Tags: window, directory

I have a folder name "Assignments" and in this folder hundreds of folders are there. Now I want a excel or notepad file of All these projects with their Name and Last Modified on text file. How I can get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a command prompt type in "Dir >> C:/Temp/Assignments.txt". The time shown on the left hand side is the modified date/time. The path is simply where you want the file to be saved to.

If you need sorting options, please visit this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Thanks, it works

But is there some method by which I can get list of only those projects which have some particular file in it with some particular extension.

Comment: If it works, I'd greatly appreciate this being marked as the answer.